# Nginx as tcp load balancer for kerberos on HBase thrift server not work

Tags: nginx, hbase, kerberos

I use below Nginx config, when the backend is HBase Thrift Server without kerberos, everything works fine, but if the backend is HBase Thrift Server with kerberos on, it always report: GSS initiate failed
Any one know why?

```
stream {
    upstream backend {
        server server1.test.com:9090;
        server server2.test.com:9090;
    }

    server {
        listen        9090;
        proxy_pass    backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kerberos was developed in the 1980's for point-to-point authentication and was never meant to work through load balancers. Indeed, the LB in itself is a kind of man-in-the-middle attack from Kerberos point of view...

Comment: Forget about load balancing, use Nginx as a "sticky" proxy for persistent sessions. With HTTP (SPNego) the initial Kerberos challenge/response must hit the same backend twice to succeed anyway; not sure about the way Thrift does that _(could use either binary or HTTP transport but even with HTTP the real auth should be managed by the binary payioad)_